# Sikuli will not "type()"

Tags: types, sikuli, sikuli-script

I have just installed Sikuli on the 5th system in our company. We are using it to automate some tasks that have to be done every day exactly the same way and are easily enough scripted with Sikuli.

It is on this 5th and final system that I ran into trouble. There is nothing that I can tell which is different on this system than any other that I have installed it on previously. Windows XP 32 bit operating system. Java 7 installed, Python 2.74 installed, and Sikuli 1.0.1.

So now, on this one, the type() function does not seem to work at all. Any of the other visual functions seem to work perfectly. It is just this type() function I am having trouble with. The log in the IDE shows that the command was sent (example: [log]TYPE "www.google.com". Can anyone shed any light on this problem? I will be happy to provide any additional information that is requested. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

When you use type command you should: type("xpto"). Some documentation: http://doc.sikuli.org/keys.html.

Another approach is use Paste command to "type" data (data previously defined) on search box (or file, or browser, ..).

Comment: You can see an example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30233637/can-sikuli-be-used-for-web-testing/31755929#31755929.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use path directly inside type()

```
    s.type("path of text field image","your text");
```