# Can Sikuli be used for web testing?

Tags: sikuli

I was working with Sikuli for desktop application like notepad,
but want to know like can I open new tab in browser using Sikuli?

Comment: What does this have to do with programming ?

Comment: @WernerVanBelle Sikuli is a visual technology used to automate GUI, so its all about programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, using Sikuli you can also automate browser. Take images of required web elements (Open new tab button in your case) and stimulate click action using Sikuli APIs.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use Sikuli for web testing.

In this code example, you can use sikuli app to: open browser --> New tab --> Give a like on a webpage (UTAD in this case):

```
click("mozilla_icon.png")

click("nova_aba.png")

click("endereco.png")

paste("www.utad.pt")

type(Key.ENTER)

wait(8)

click("like_btt.png")

wait(5)
```

Images of sikuli code:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: @Babban Chandak --You try what I answer?

Answer (score 0):

yes you can use sikuli for performing open tab first take the image of new tab control like in case of FF https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B09BIsDTY_AuZFpMWko1U3BFc0E/view?usp=sharing .Save this image on you local machine. But make sure that image which is used for reference is visible on screen.Call the function mentioned below by and give it Absolute path to above mentioned image.

```
//provide absolute path in img 
public void click_Image(String img)
{
     s = new DesktopScreenRegion();
    target = new ImageTarget(new File(img));
     r = s.find(target);

    // Create a mouse object
     mouse = new DesktopMouse();
    // Use the mouse object to click on the center of the target region
    mouse.click(r.getCenter()); 

}
```

Comment: OP have experience in using SIkuli with Notepad, he wants to know if same can be used to automate browser.

Comment: IS this fine now Karna ?

Comment: Thanks for all your comments,so now am aware that sikuli works on browser,so i am working over it.will check if its run correctly.

Comment: Can any one help me out to open new tab in browser using sikul4net,as i wan to run in c#

Comment: @Babban Chandak--you can always use the applicable keyboard shortcuts to manipulate your browser. Opening a new tab would be   type("t", Key.CTRL) for most browsers, though I've never used Sikuli with C#, the principle should still be the same.